# Adding a template file by relative path in Prometheus Alertmanager

Tags: relative-path, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Suppose my alert manager setting file uses a template file located in the same directory as the setting file :

say, 
`/users/someAddress/settings.yml` &
`/users/someAddress/myTemplate.tmpl`

Currently i use :

`templates:
- '/users/someAddress/myTemplate.tmpl'`
 to refer to it. Can i use a relative path like /myTemplate.tmpl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Except `/myTemplate.tmpl` is not a relative path. `myTemplate.tmpl` is.